# Can Delayed Secondaries in MongoDB ever win an Election and become Primary?

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

In a MongoDB replica set, we can force a certain delay on secondary nodes. What I'm unable to understand is that even though these nodes (delayed ones) participate in Election, can they ever become Primary ? If they can, then what happens to their delayed preference, does it warn off automatically ?

Answer (score 2):

They can become primary, so they should have a priority of 0 and be set as hidden to prevent them from becoming primary.

> Delayed members must have a priority set to 0 to prevent them from becoming primary in their replica sets. Also these members should be hidden to prevent your application from seeing or querying this member.

source: [Delayed Members](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/replica-sets/#replica-set-delayed-members).

You can find more details about election internals at this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-internals/#replica-set-election-internals).

Comment: Thanks! That helps. Actually, I read documentation before posting this question, but I couldn't find this information. Maybe I oversaw it.